# More efficient SQL to count from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

I have a really slow SQL statement which I believe I can optimise using conditional count() statements but I can't work out how to do this.

```
SELECT TOP 10 U.UserID,
                U.Fullname,
                U.URL,
                U.Fname,
                U.ProfilePic,

  (SELECT Count(ResourceID)
   FROM resources R
   WHERE R.UserID = U.UserID) AS ResourcesPosted,

  (SELECT Count(JobID)
   FROM Jobs J
   WHERE J.UserID = U.UserID) AS JobsPosted,

  (SELECT Count(AuditID)
   FROM Audit_Trail AT
   WHERE AT.UserID = U.UserID
     AND TYPE = 1
     AND Entry LIKE '%logged in%') AS TotalLogins,

  (SELECT Count(EventID)
   FROM Future_Events_Listing E
   WHERE E.UserID = U.UserID) AS EventsPosted
FROM User_basics U
LEFT JOIN Pod_Membership PM ON PM.userID = U.UserID
WHERE PodID = 268
```

Could I do some sort of inner join and then conditionally count the items?

Comment: Is `PodID` in the `Pod_Membership` table? If so the 'LEFT JOIN` should be an `INNER JOIN` as the `WHERE` turns it into such anyway.

Comment: @strickt01 thanks, I've done that now.

Comment: Is UserID indexed on the tables you are performing the `COUNT` on - that's your probable issue? If there is no association between the other tables you are counting on other than UserID then there is no condition on the `COUNT` you can apply other than the one already in the `WHERE` clause - i.e. UserID.

Answer (score 0):

Use "explain" to find out how the query is being executed.

If it is not using indexes, index your tables. As a general rule, put an index on any field which is included in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see exactly where the bottleneck is without a query plan. The most likely problem is that there is no index on `UserID` in the tables which you are performing the `COUNT` on. If this is the case then your query will be causing a full table scan on each table for each user. So the following query might help avoid this eventuality as it will perform just one table scan for each table (although indexing UserID is the best solution as this should just result in an index seek on each table - with the possible exception of Audit_trail as you may need to include `Type` and `Entry` in your index in order to avoid a potentially very expensive key lookup):

```
 SELECT TOP 10 U.UserID,
            U.Fullname,
            U.URL,
            U.Fname,
            U.ProfilePic,
            ResourcesPosted,
            JobsPosted,
            TotalLogins,
            EventsPosted

 FROM User_basics U

 INNER JOIN Pod_Membership PM ON PM.userID = U.UserID
 AND PodID = 268

 LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT R.UserID, Count(ResourceID) AS ResourcesPosted
    FROM resources R
    GROUP BY R.UserID) res
    ON res.UserID = U.UserID

 LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT J.UserID, Count(JobID) AS JobsPosted
 FROM Jobs J
 GROUP BY J.UserID ) job
 ON job.UserID = U.UserID

 LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT AT.UserID, Count(AuditID) AS TotalLogins
    FROM Audit_Trail AT
 WHERE TYPE = 1
 AND Entry LIKE '%logged in%'
 GROUP BY AT.UserID) aud
 ON aud.UserID = U.UserID

 LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT E.UserID, Count(EventID) AS EventsPosted
    FROM Future_Events_Listing E
    GROUP BY E.UserID)  fut
    ON fut.UserID = U.UserID
```

So:

1) If there is no index on `UserId` in any or all tables then consider adding one.

2) If there is an index on `Audit_Trail` for `UserID` then you may need to add `Entry` and `Type` as included columns to avoid a key lookup. You will need to inspect the query plan to assess this.